# Rails Relation#update_all consumes more memory than Relation#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The `Relation#update(id, attributes)` docs mentions that "The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.", while the `Relation#update_all(updates, conditions = nil, options = {})` states that no instantiations, callbacks or validations are made (straight DB query).

Running a simple performance test and replacing `Relation#update` with `Relation#update_all`, it looks like the memory consumption have increased.

Any explanation?

Excerpt:

```
#Before
MyModel.update(my_hash['id'], special_attrs)

#After (more memory consumed)
MyModel.where(:id => my_hash['id']).update_all(special_attrs)

#Update-2 (slightly more memory consumed than with update(id, attrs)
MyModel.update_all(special_attrs, {:id => my_hash['id']})
```

- Windows XP (yeh - I know)
- JRuby 1.6.8 (1.9)
- Rails 3.2.8

**UPDATE** - Some basic numbers for comparison: 
For around 700 update statements fired, there's a difference of around 0.6MB (0.8kB per statement)

**UPDATE 2** - Removed AREL chaining as per @philip-hallstrom suggestion. Slight reduction in memory footprint but still `MyModel.update_all(attrs, conditions)` is consuming more memory than `MyModel.update(id, attrs)`.

Comment: how much difference in memory are we talking about ?

Comment: updated the question with some numbers

Answer (score 0):

Is there a difference if you do:

`MyModel.update_all(special_attrs, {:id => my_hash['id']})`

I didn't dig too far, but it looks like update_all calls Arel right off the bat.  I stopped looking after `.update -> .update_attributes -> .assign_attributes` and didn't see Arel at all, although I'm sure it must come into play at some point.

If I had to guess, I'd say that's why.

I assume that this is in a loop somewhere?  Otherwise, why not just do:

`MyModel.update_all(special_attrs, {:id => all_my_hash_ids_as_an_array})`

Comment: A slight improvement but still `MyModel.update_all(attrs, conditions)` is consuming more memory than `MyModel.update(id, attrs)`. Will update the question.